# Pandas get all rows in dataframe A that contain substring of dataframe B

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have 2 dataframes,

dataframe 1:
[image]

dataframe 2:
[image]

I would like to get all rows in dataframe1 that contains substring of columnB in dataframe 2:

[image]

Im using `df1['columnA'].isin(df2['columnB'])` but i cant get this working.

How should i achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO; if the answer resolved your issue, kindly accept it - see [`What should I do when someone answers my question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"columnA":["apple, orange","pear, apple, lemon","banana, pear","cherry, pear, lemon"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"columnB":["apple","cherry"]})

out = df1[df1.columnA.str.contains('|'.join(df2.columnB.values))]
```

Then your output `DataFrame` would be:

```
>>> out
               columnA
0        apple, orange
1   pear, apple, lemon
3  cherry, pear, lemon
```

### How it works

`'|'.join(df2.columnB.values)` would result in `'apple|cherry'` as it joins the values of the `columnB` of `df2` using the `|` connector.

Then the `str.contains` function searchs for apple or cherry word (`|` works as or) within the `columnA` in `df1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do list comprehension with:

```
df1[df1['columnA'].apply(lambda x: any([y for y in x for z in df2['columnB'] if y in z]))]
```

First, you have to make sure that your comma-separated list is actually a python list though with `df1['columnA'] = df1['columnA'].str.split(',')`

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.DataFrame({'columnA' : ['apple,orange', 'pear,apple,lemon','banana,pear','cherry,pear,lemon']})
df1['columnA'] = df1['columnA'].str.split(',')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'columnB' : ['apple','cherry']})
df1 = df1[df1['columnA'].apply(lambda x: any([y for y in x for z in df2['columnB'] if y in z]))]
df1
```

output:

```
    columnA
0   [apple, orange]
1   [pear, apple, lemon]
3   [cherry, pear, lemon]
```

The list comprehension works by checking if `any` of each `df1['columnA']` value within the list of each row is in `df2['columnB']`. `y` represents the individual items within each row list of `df1['columnA']`, and `x` represents each row of `df1['columnA']`. Finally, `z` represents each row of `df2['columnB']`. So, ultimately, you need to return `True` if any of the `y` list items are in `z` using `any` and `False` if not in order to setup for boolean masking to filter out unneeded rows that contain `False`, i.e. no matches for any items within any given row of `df1['columnA']`.